# How to add views to overlay on map?

Tags: android, google-maps, view, overlay

I want to know if there is a way to extend overlays in order to make them able to display views on specific locations on a map.

If that's possible could you help me with code snippets or links I looked online but couldn't find anything that really helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the RelativeLayout like this way.

here is the example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true" android:apiKey="you key" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/cur_loc" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/cur_loc"
            android:visibility="gone" android:padding="0dip"
            android:layout_margin="0dip" android:background="#ffffff" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/track_dist_linear"
        android:background="#ffffff" android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/txt_msg" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000" android:text="Distance 0 km"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/speed_msg" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000" android:text="Speed 0 kmph \ntime 0 sec"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/track_dist_linear">
        <Button android:id="@+id/track_btn" android:text="Start" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/show_track_btn" android:text="Show" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: first thank you for your reply, may be i wasn't clear enough: i don't want to add overlayitem (marker) but a view (button, textview..) and place them on map so they would move if i animate the mapview

Comment: check updated post. by the way I think no need to add button or view using overlay you can use the same overlay and display button image as like marker on map so it will be move on the map